# MySQL remove all whitespaces from the entire column

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to remove all whitespaces from a specific column for all values?

Comment: When you have to remove white spaces? by update or select? not clear!

Answer (score 272, accepted):

To replace `all spaces` :

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, ' ', '')
```

To remove all `tabs` characters :

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, '\t', '' )
```

To remove all `new line` characters :

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(`col_name`, '\n', '')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

To remove `first and last space(s)` of column :

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = TRIM(`col_name`)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

and if you want remove all type of spaces, you can combine all of this functions :

```sql
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`col_name`, ' ', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '');
```

Comment: `TRIM` only removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: That works :) Although it obviously only removes spaces and not tabs or newlines. Not clear exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: if you want to remove tabs just do this
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = REPLACE( `col_name` , '\t' , '' )

Comment: To remove the new line : UPDATE `table ` set col_name = REPLACE( col_name , '\r' , '' );

Comment: how about double or triple space?

Comment: @reignsly no problem, this code remove **all** spaces when using `REPLACE` function

Comment: To remove the new line I suggest: UPDATE table set col_name = REPLACE( col_name , '\r\n' , '' );

Comment: What if you only want to replace whitespace between characters and not from the beginning or end of a string?

Answer (score 18):

Since the question is how to replace ALL whitespaces

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `col_name` = REPLACE
(REPLACE(REPLACE(`col_name`, ' ', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '');
```

Comment: This works for me. It completely removes all kinds of white space.

Answer (score 12):

Working Query:

`SELECT replace(col_name , ' ','') FROM table_name;`

While this doesn't :

`SELECT trim(col_name) FROM table_name;`

Comment: using this 'replace' in WHERE clause is a big help to search and prevent similar data saving in database. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using below query you can remove leading and trailing whitespace in a MySQL.

```
UPDATE `table_name`
SET `col_name` = TRIM(`col_name`);
```

Comment: This actually only removes spaces, not all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following sql, you are done:

> `SELECT replace(CustomerName,' ', '') FROM Customers;`

you can test this sample over here: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in)

Comment: The question was how to  "remove all whitespaces from a specific column for all values" which your answer doesn't, not to mention the answer in May was better.

Answer (score 0):

Note: there are two types of white spaces, those that come from the space bar and those that come from the tab button, you need to do a replace for both.  I suspect this is why the TRIM function seems not to always work.

so

```
replace(replace(<field_name>,' ',''),'  ','')
```

(there could be more types of white spaces, but these are the two I have found)

Answer (score 0):

this works on me

`UPDATE table  SET col_name= TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col_name, '\r', ' '), '\n', ' '), '\t', ' '));`