# MySQL TRIM to clean up table littered with spaces

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 14,000 rows.  One particular Column has a lot of blank spaces in the data.

I am a mySql Newbie and can't get the syntax correct to trim the white space.

Here is maybes guess ( i know the where close looks funny )

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET myColumn=TRIM(myColumn)
WHERE ID > 0
```

What is the syntax?

Comment: your syntax is correct but trim only removes the while spaces from beginning and end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql remove all whitespaces from the entire column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313803/mysql-remove-all-whitespaces-from-the-entire-column)

Comment: In such a situation if I really needed to do it I would do a replace of 2 spaces with 1 space, and repeat that multiple times. But I would be deeply concerned that the spaces in the data is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `col_name` = TRIM( `col_name` )
```