# how to use trim() and update all rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big table in mysql. Around the string in my record is waste space, something like this:

```
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|        anything           |           anything         |
----------------------------------------------------------
|        anything           |           anything         |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Now i want this:

```
+--------+--------+
|anything|anything|
-------------------
|anything|anything|
+--------+--------+
```

In fact i want to use `trim()` for all rows and update them. how can i do that ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html Edit: if you want to replace spaces in the table itself. Otherwise, use @MarkBaker's method.

Comment: `UPDATE mytablename SET col1 = TRIM(col1), col2 = TRIM(col2), ...` - [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)

Comment: @MarkBaker is it possible that i use php function (trim) in sql codes ?!

Comment: Why would you want to use a PHP function? MySQL has a perfectly good TRIM() function of its own - I've already linked to it

Comment: @stack TRIM() is a MySQL function, too: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313803/mysql-remove-all-whitespaces-from-the-entire-column

Comment: What's the data type are these?

Comment: `TRIM()` is an SQL function. `trim()` is a PHP function. If you are looking to update your SQL table, you can do this via SQL code alone.

Comment: @MarkBaker tnx buddy, just one another question, how can i use `TRIM()` and `REPLACE()` in one query ? Is it possible ?

Comment: You can "nest" MySQL functions just as you can "nest" PHP functions: `UPDATE mytablename SET col1 = TRIM(REPLACE(col1, '  ', ' ')), col2 = TRIM(REPLACE(col2, '  ', ' ')), ...` though if you want to remove __all__ spaces, just use REPLACE() instead of TRIM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in several the comments:

```
UPDATE sometable SET column1 = TRIM(column1), column2 = TRIM(column2);
```