# Remove tabs,new line etc from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, replace, special-characters

I need to remove multi spaces, tab, new line, carriage return, form feed or vertical tab from MySQL table's field.

Here [How to remove duplicate white spaces in string using Java?](http://tab,%20new%20line,%20carriage%20return,%20form%20feed%20or%20vertical%20tab)

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

I found the result what I have expected but in JAVA. I need the same result in MySQL.

Also I need to replace all single quotes to double quotes.

How to do it .

Comment: There does not appear to be a single MySQL function which can remove all whitespace characters in one go, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313803/mysql-remove-all-whitespaces-from-the-entire-column).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, ' ', '');
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, '\t', '' );
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, '\n', '');
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, '\r', '');
```

or

```
UPDATE `table` set `field` = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,' ',''),'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));
```

or create the following stored procedure and call it to remove more that one whitespace characters in a row

```
DELIMITER |
    CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE affected INT DEFAULT 1; 
       WHILE affected > 0 DO
         UPDATE `table` set `field` = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`field`,' ',''),'\t',''),'\n',''),'\r',''));
         SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO affected;  
       END WHILE; 
    END |
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks.  UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, ' ', ''); is not working for more than two or three spaces.

Comment: Use a stored procedure to execute the query until there is no whitespace left.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue with the "VT" (Vertical Tab) character.

Following worked for us:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field` = REPLACE(`field`, CHAR(11), '');
```

And to locate data with this character, we used this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE INSTR(`field`, char(11)) > 0;
```