# How to remove more than one space between 2 or more words?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove spaces between strings. The space count is not fixed. How to do this?
ex:

```
'ABCD   123'
'ABCD         123'
```

Comment: What are "unwanted spaces"?, duplicates or any or...?

Comment: All of them, or do you want to keep one space between the strings?

Comment: What is the version of your DB ?

Comment: @JackU This is a MySQL, not SQL Server, question.

Comment: The solution can be found in related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313803/mysql-remove-all-whitespaces-from-the-entire-column

Comment: Want to keep one space and my mysql version is 5.2

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `replace()` trick:

```
select replace(replace(replace(col, ' ', '><'), '<>', ''), '><', ' ')
```

This assumes that the string does not contain the characters used for the replacement.  (Any pair of characters can be used.)

If your string is always of the form suggested -- two strings with spaces only in the middle, you could also do:

```
select concat(substring_index(col, ' ', 1), ' ',
              substring_index(col, ' ', -1)
             )
```

EDIT:

If you want to remove *all* spaces, then simply do:

```
replace(str, ' ', '')
```

The above is to leave one space.

Comment: I am not that familiar with all this so could you please explain why you need to go through all these steps instead of   

    replace(col, ' ' , '')   
Or are you trying to maintain a single space between the text still, end result being 'ABCD 123'

Comment: @TineO . . . This is to convert all instances of multiple spaces into a single space.

Comment: I figured as much. He didnt specify in the question, but I thought that maybe there was some problem with simply replacing ' ' with ''

Answer (score 4):

To round off the answers, in MySQL 8+ we can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[ ]+', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want to keep one space in between words, then just make the replacement a single space instead of empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the larger scope of what you are using this for, I would recommend looking into the replace function.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[MYSQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

```
REPLACE('ABCD   123',' ','')
```

Comment: Nothe that OP has added a <mysql> tag, so a link to that documentation would probably be more useful.

Comment: I added the MYSQL reference, but without knowing which of the 2 they are using, I would find the microsoft documentation to be more beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring_index`

```
set @str='ABC 123';

select concat(a , b) as "Result String"
  from
   (
     select substring_index(@str,' ',1) a ,substring_index(@str,' ',-1) b
   ) q;

Result String
-------------
ABC123
```

Comment: Number of words are not fixed. There could be 3 or more words in one string.

Comment: @AshishKarnavat if your DB's version is 8, then you can use Tim's method easily, but this doesn't work for multiple spaces.